# What seductive humanoid (or similar) monsters are there?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

I know about nymphs and succubi, but is there any other monster in the lore that is extremely beautiful and humanoid-like or similar that seduces people?

Even a high-Charisma humanoid monster would do. The more exotic looking the better.

I am looking for humanoid entries in the monster with high-charisma/diplomacy skills; the lower CR the better, the more exotic-looking the better. Bonus points if the entry specifically evokes a great beauty or good artistic/social skills. Fey are okay, but non-native outsiders may be a problem (in other words, I'm looking for something that can be found on the Material Plane).

Comment: Does it matter what the general alignment of the creature is?

Comment: What makes “a hot member of any humanoid-ish race” not a good answer to this question? This seems like a never ending list question consisting of every race that has a bonus to any number of things, from “Nocticula” to “the local bartender.”

Comment: When you say "humanoid", do you mean the humanoid [creature type](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#TOC-Humanoid) or a generally human-shaped body?

Comment: human-shaped body.

Comment: humanoid body shape. I don't care much for alignement, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There are way too many

I suggest you take a look at the [NPC Index on Archives of Nethys](https://www.aonprd.com/NPCs.aspx?SubGroup=All) and look up everything that has levels in **Bard**, or have suggestive names, like the [Prostitute](https://www.aonprd.com/NPCDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Street%20(Prostitute)) or the [Seductive Rogue](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/npc-s/npcs-cr-4/human-expert-2-rogue-4/).

For non-humanoid creatures, there are even more. We have the notorious creatures that are labelled as "seducers" by the developers, like [Amanusya](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/rakshasa/rakshasa-amanusya/), [Erodaemon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/daemons/erodaemon/) or even [Nocticula](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/demon-lords/demon-lord-nocticula/) herself, the queen of succubi.

But really, any creature with enough ranks in [Diplomacy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/diplomacy/) or [Bluff](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/bluff/), or even access to [Charm Person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person/), could be a good fit for a seducer. Creatures like [Vampires](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire/), [Satyrs](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/satyr/) and [Green Hags](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/hag/hag-green/) are known for being good examples of "charmers".